# CSV fputcsv delimiter ";" "," with desktop and mobile

Tags: php, excel, csv, mobile, desktop

When I open the file I created with a delimiter "," on the computer all content is written in one cell

[image]

but when I use ";" delimiter all work fine

[image]

and the mobile phone is a different story, it all works the other way around, when I use delimiter "," all work fine, but when I use ";" all content is written in one cell, how on the computer when I use "," delimiter. How to make it work on both devices ?

```
function array2csv(array &$array, array $arr1)
{
    if (count($array) == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    ob_start();
    $df = fopen("php://output", 'w');
    fputcsv($df, array_keys(reset($array)), ';');
//    fputcsv($df, $arr1, ';');

    foreach ($array as $row) {
        fputcsv($df, $row, ';');
    }
    fclose($df);
    return ob_get_clean();
}

function download_send_headers($filename)
{
    // disable caching
    $now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
    header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
    header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");

    // force download
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");

    // disposition / encoding on response body
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
}

download_send_headers($_POST['user_id'] . '-(' . date("Y-m-d") . ')-olimob' . ".csv");
echo array2csv($array, $arr1);
die();
```

Comment: That's a software (Excel, OpenOffice Calc, ...) configuration.

Comment: ok, but how can I fix this problem? Can I do something like that on both devices displayed normally?

Comment: Does your file have a `.csv` extension? MS Excel can guess but it's not perfect at detecting the data that your file is formatted with.

Comment: Sure download_send_headers($_POST['user_id'] . '-(' . date("Y-m-d") . ')-olimob' . ".csv"); here a file is created with the format .csv

Comment: You need to configure both devices (programs) to use "," or ";" as a delimiter. As far as I know, there is not you can do on PHP side.

Comment: So, I need to track the device and use different delimiters depending on the device? And on the side of PHP, I can not do anything?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a client-side (MS Excel) configuration issue. Based on your PHP code, the CSV file is being properly generated.

Comment: Take a look at https://superuser.com/a/407085/259665

Answer (score 0):

It's not configurable in MS Excel unless you can change your locale settings... that's what determines whether `,` or `;` is used as the delimiter for a csv file...

However, what you can do is create a first line of

```
sep=;
```

and then use a `;` separator, and modern versions of MS Excel will then read the file correctly regardless of locale-settings

Comment: What does it mean to create a first line of  sep=; ? when I do with such a delimiter on mobile phones does not work